# CircleCI and Heroku automatic deployment

Tags: heroku, deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

I'm trying to configure automatic deploy on Heroku integrated with CircleCI.

On Heroku Dashboard, at the Deploy tab, I have the option to configure an automatic deploy for a specific branch and there is an option "Wait for CI to pass before deploy". What happens when I have both this and the circle.yml configured for an automated deploy on Heroku? Will the app be deployed twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will.
CircleCi and Heroku will trigger building and deploying process at the same time